# @Formula annotation gives an exception when entity is saved in RepositoryItemWriter

Tags: java, jpa, spring-batch, hibernate-annotations

I have an entity which is used by RepositoryItemWriter in a step and RepositoryItemReader in next step. I want to populate a value in entity class when it is loaded in the second step. that value is populated by database function.
My entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "swt_dx_file_eod")
@Data
public class TransactionFileEod {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "trxn_no")
    private long trxnNo;
    @Column(name = "msg_type")
    private String msgType;
    @Column(name = "bit_map")
    private String bitMap;
    @Column(name = "proc_code")
    private String processingCode;
    @Column(name = "trxn_amt")
    private String transactionAmount;
    @Column(name = "trxn_date_time")
    private String transactionDateTime;
    @Column(name = "pos_data_code")
    private String posDataCode;
    @Column(name = "merc_cat_code")
    private String merchantCategoryCode;
    @Column(name = "crd_no")
    private String cardNo;
    @Formula("select get_data(cardNo)")
    private String decryptedCardNo;
    @Column(name = "retr_ref_no")
    private String retrievalReferenceNo;
    @Column(name = "auth_code")
    private String approvalCode;
    @Column(name = "term_id")
    private String terminalId;
    @Column(name = "crd_acpt_id_code")
    private String merchantId;
    @Column(name = "crd_acpt_name_loc")
    private String cardAcceptorNameLocation;
}
```

ItemWriter

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public RepositoryItemWriter<TransactionFileEod> transactionLoadItemWriter(){
        try{
            return new RepositoryItemWriterBuilder<TransactionFileEod>().methodName("save").repository(transactionFileEodRepository).build();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

ItemReader

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public RepositoryItemReader<TransactionFileEod> transactionRepositoryReader(TransactionFileEodRepository transactionFileEodRepository
            , @Value("#{jobParameters[" + PARAM_CUTOFF_DATE_TIME + "]}") LocalDateTime cutoffDate){
        try {
            return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<TransactionFileEod>()
                    .methodName("findByaddedDate").name("transactionFileReader")
                    .arguments(Arrays.asList(cutoffDate.toLocalDate()))
                    .sorts(Collections.singletonMap("trxnNo", Sort.Direction.ASC))
                    .repository(transactionFileEodRepository)
                    .pageSize(GLOBAL_CHUNK_SIZE)
                    .build();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Following exception is thrown when first step is started

```
2023-07-04T23:25:23.961+05:30 ERROR 11616 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step swedbank.eod.file_gen.etl.to.file.step in job swedbank.eod.file_gen.job

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select t1_0.trxn_no,t1_0.added_date,t1_0.auth_code,t1_0.bit_map,t1_0.crd_acpt_name_loc,t1_0.crd_no,select get_data(t1_0.cardNo),t1_0.p_55,t1_0.exp_date,t1_0.merc_cat_code,t1_0.crd_acpt_id_code,t1_0.msg_type,t1_0.p_47,t1_0.p_48,t1_0.p_60,t1_0.p_61,t1_0.p_63,t1_0.pos_data_code,t1_0.proc_code,t1_0.retr_ref_no,t1_0.service_code,t1_0.term_id,t1_0.trxn_amt,t1_0.trxn_curr_code,t1_0.trxn_date_time from swt_dx_file_eod t1_0 where t1_0.trxn_no=?] [ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 100] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy110.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:283) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemWriter.doInvoke(RepositoryItemWriter.java:151) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemWriter.doWrite(RepositoryItemWriter.java:121) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemWriter.write(RepositoryItemWriter.java:97) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemWriter$$SpringCGLIB$$0.write(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:203) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:170) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:227) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:389) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:313) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:256) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:362) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:206) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:139) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:241) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:227) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:153) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:167) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:142) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:316) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select t1_0.trxn_no,t1_0.added_date,t1_0.auth_code,t1_0.bit_map,t1_0.crd_acpt_name_loc,t1_0.crd_no,select get_data(t1_0.cardNo),t1_0.p_55,t1_0.exp_date,t1_0.merc_cat_code,t1_0.crd_acpt_id_code,t1_0.msg_type,t1_0.p_47,t1_0.p_48,t1_0.p_60,t1_0.p_61,t1_0.p_63,t1_0.pos_data_code,t1_0.proc_code,t1_0.retr_ref_no,t1_0.service_code,t1_0.term_id,t1_0.trxn_amt,t1_0.trxn_curr_code,t1_0.trxn_date_time from swt_dx_file_eod t1_0 where t1_0.trxn_no=?] [ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 100] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3381) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3371) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromCacheOrDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:588) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:557) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:550) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadWithRegularProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1219) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.internal.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.internal.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.internal.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.internal.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1024) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.lambda$entityIsDetached$0(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.LoadQueryInfluencers.fromInternalFetchProfile(LoadQueryInfluencers.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:319) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.merge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.doMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:834) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:640) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 100
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    ... 116 common frames omitted
```

I want to populate this field when loaded from database in step2

Comment: It is SQL not JPQL. So you need to reference the SQL columnname not the JPQL property name.

Comment: there is no such column named 'decryptedCardNo'. I want to populate that from a db function. That's why I used @Formula("select get_data(cardNo)") for that field

Comment: Again it is SQL... There is no `cardNo` column in your database.

Comment: I corrected it. but still the error appears.
'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select t1_0.trxn_no,t1_0.added_date,t1_0.auth_code,t1_0.bit_map,t1_0.crd_acpt_name_loc,t1_0.crd_no,select get_data(t1_0.crd_no),t1_0.p_55,t1_0.exp_date,t1_0.merc_cat_code,t1_0.crd_acpt_id_code,t1_0.msg_type,t1_0.p_47,t1_0.p_48,t1_0.p_60,t1_0.p_61,t1_0.p_63,t1_0.pos_data_code,t1_0.proc_code,t1_0.retr_ref_no,t1_0.service_code,t1_0.term_id,t1_0.trxn_amt,t1_0.trxn_curr_code,t1_0.trxn_date_time from swt_dx_file_eod t1_0 where t1_0.trxn_no=?]'

Comment: You don't need the `select` part. You only need to call the function.

Comment: Yes now it works. thank you very much! this reduces my step execution time by 5x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M.Deinum suggested in comments; first to use column name as in DB. Second to remove select statement. this solved the issue and able to call the database procedure at loading the entity